# react-resizeable has no handle on the bottom right

Tags: reactjs

I am using react-resizable , I create a demo based on the demo code here:

```
import React from 'react';
import Draggable, { DraggableCore } from 'react-draggable';
import { Resizable, ResizableBox } from 'react-resizable';
import './style.css';
// import 'react-resizable/css/style.css';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Draggable>
        <ResizableBox handle={<div />} width={200} height={200}>
          <div
            style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
          >
            123
          </div>
        </ResizableBox>
      </Draggable>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want the content can be resizable and draggable at the same time. now it can be draggable but I don't see the resize handle on the right bottom. I think it may be caused by the css import. but if I uncomment the line `import 'react-resizable/css/style.css'` stackblitz says `Can't find package:react-resizable`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-n7qk3n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 issues here:

1. Your handle is not correct, so just remove it
2. Your re-sizable will not work inside draggable like this without any customization or handling re sizable to be draggable and so on...
3. You are miss to include the re-sizable style...

final code:

```
<div>
  <ResizableBox width={200} height={200}>
    <div
      style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
    >
      123
    </div>
  </ResizableBox>
</div>
```

style:

```
.react-resizable {
  position: relative;
}
.react-resizable-handle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-origin: content-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA2IDYiIHN0eWxlPSJiYWNrZ3JvdW5kLWNvbG9yOiNmZmZmZmYwMCIgeD0iMHB4IiB5PSIwcHgiIHdpZHRoPSI2cHgiIGhlaWdodD0iNnB4Ij48ZyBvcGFjaXR5PSIwLjMwMiI+PHBhdGggZD0iTSA2IDYgTCAwIDYgTCAwIDQuMiBMIDQgNC4yIEwgNC4yIDQuMiBMIDQuMiAwIEwgNiAwIEwgNiA2IEwgNiA2IFoiIGZpbGw9IiMwMDAwMDAiLz48L2c+PC9zdmc+');
  background-position: bottom right;
  padding: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
.react-resizable-handle-sw {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: sw-resize;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.react-resizable-handle-se {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: se-resize;
}
.react-resizable-handle-nw {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: nw-resize;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.react-resizable-handle-ne {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: ne-resize;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.react-resizable-handle-w,
.react-resizable-handle-e {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  cursor: ew-resize;
}
.react-resizable-handle-w {
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.react-resizable-handle-e {
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}
.react-resizable-handle-n,
.react-resizable-handle-s {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  cursor: ns-resize;
}
.react-resizable-handle-n {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}
.react-resizable-handle-s {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

[Demo link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yrirts?file=src%2FApp.js)

Suggetion:
You have another nice library allow you to handle and custmize drag and resize in one way, I use it in real project and its amazing...[React RND](https://github.com/bokuweb/react-rnd)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. React RND is amazing, but it seems not to work with a modal https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-modal-rnd-2?file=rnd.js .

Comment: You are welcome, I think you need to build a custom modal component since the original modal will create dom at bottom of html...and issue will resolved

Comment: Can confirm react-rnd just works. No fussing around